# How to list upcoming events with pictures and updating registration links?

Tags: wordpress, civievent

we would like to be able to have an image be associated with an event so that it could be displayed in the event listings.

Currently, we display our upcoming 4 classes on our WordPress page with links to the Civicrm event sign-up pages. This is working ok, but means we manually have to change things over on the website, also for repeating events.
Is there a way to link to the event series rather than just the next repeating event?

We looked into the CiviEvent List Widget but couldn't find an option to have it display at least one picture per event to make it more appealing for potential customers.

Is there an option/extension that can automatically display the next 4 or 5 events with an option to include a picture with automatically updating registration links?

Thank you for your help,

Comment: Did you try wp plugin to list all the event ? that should work as excepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [CiviCRM Event Organiser](https://github.com/christianwach/civicrm-event-organiser), which syncs events between [Event Organiser](https://wordpress.org/plugins/event-organiser/) and CiviCRM. If you create your events in WordPress via Event Organiser then each event can be assigned a Feature Image. Here's [an example listing](https://spirit-of-football.de/events/event/upcoming-events/) where some events have Feature Images. As a bonus for busy sites, you get [a nice calendar](https://spirit-of-football.de/kalender/) that comes as standard with Event Organiser.

Sync works with repeating events if they are created in Event Organiser and then synced to CiviCRM - but not the other way round yet. Each event that has been synced to CiviCRM will have a link to the relevant CiviCRM registration page on its standalone page but it's possible to inject this into the archive template too.

It has to be said, however, that this is a fairly heavyweight solution and can take a fair bit of setting up so YMMV, caveat emptor, etc etc. I would strongly recommend installing on a development version of your site (or a test site) first.

Comment: This looks very promising. How does it work with paid events? Am I able to go into the civicrm after it is synced from wordpress to add the payment features as normal in civicrm? Thanks for the help

Comment: Yes, works like normal.